# Browsable API in Laravel 5?

Tags: api, rest, laravel-5, browsable

Is there an equivalent to [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) in Laravel 5 on this subject? It would be nice if there was a tool that generates pages in which the client can navigate through the api tree and where I can test my api endpoints without writing front-end code for each of them.

Comment: Yes, there is now, I basically copied Django REST Framework's Browsable API, it's a simple HTML rendition, with URLs linkified
https://github.com/stevelacey/laravel-browsable-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger will help you out here. It's not quite as automagical as what Django REST Framework gives you unfortunately and you have to write the documentation for your API endpoints yourself.

Here's a [good introduction](https://www.marcoraddatz.com/en/2015/07/21/integrate-swagger-into-laravel/) to working with Swagger in a Laravel app. You should also consider adding [Swaggervel](https://github.com/slampenny/Swaggervel) into your project as this takes out some of the leg work of tying Swagger support into your app.